# Configure Tomcat/Catalina to serve application at root on port 80

Tags: java, tomcat

I don't usually work with Java applications, but am trying to set up and configure a [Java-based, open-source wiki](http://www.xwiki.org). I have it up and running by installing using APT on Ubuntu. Its default url is `localhost:8080/xwiki`. I want to configure tomcat, or catalina, or whatever so that it is available on port 80 and at the domain root. I'm setting this up as a subdomain: `wiki.example.com`

How can I configure this in Tomcat?

Comment: This is a very common problem and well documented. What have you tried as search words so far?

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to conf folder in tomcat installation directory

e.g. C:\Tomcat 6.0\conf\

2) Edit following tag in server.xml file

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

3) Change the port=8080 value to port=80

4) Save file.

Comment: that might solve the port 80 problem, but not the root path problem.

Comment: what is the root problem?

Comment: I mentioned that the url is like this: `localhost:8080/xwiki`, I want to remove the `/xwiki` part of it so it is located at the root of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the only way to run process on a [privileged port (less than 1024)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-open-ports/) requires running your process as root.

This is bad from a security standpoint, and an acceptable alternative is to use iptables to forward requests destined to port 80 to your application servers port.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

This will mitigate any major security threats by running your server as root and still allow your process to work over the standard port 80.

Also to answer your question about getting your application to run without specifying the application name in the url check this out:
http://benhutchison.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/how-to-configure-tomcat-root-context/

Answer (score 1):

Based on many recommendations, I decided not to try and use tomcat to serve the application on port 80. Instead, I set up Apache as a reverse proxy and kept tomcat with its default settings. Here's what I did to configure Apache on Ubuntu:

1. install apache: `sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork`
2. enable the proxy apache modules: `sudo a2enmod proxy_http`
3. create a virtual host file in /etc/apache2/sites-available with the following contents:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName wiki.yourdomain.com

     RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://wiki.yourdomain.com/xwiki/

     ProxyPass /xwiki http://localhost:8080/xwiki
     ProxyPassReverse /xwiki http://localhost:8080/xwiki

     DocumentRoot /var/www
     <Directory "/var/www/">
       Options -Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Allow from all
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. restart apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

See server.xml and edit your configuration settings like port number, root directory etc.

Comment: I did not see any configuration settings for root directory. Also I changed the port number to 80 and restarted tomcat, and in the catalina.out log file, it gives me an error that it doesn't have permission to bind to port 80 (even though I restarted tomcat as root).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [mod_vhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost.html), described [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html).